# simple_salesforce bulk query - timed out

Tags: bulk-api, python, simple-salesforce

I'm encountering timeout errors when fetching records from Salesforce via the simple_salesforce library and executing a SOQL query, particularly during bulk updates for a specific date. Currently, the timeout limit is set to 90. Is there a method to retrieve records in batches to mitigate this issue? Any advice or examples on how to handle this would be highly valued. Below is the relevant section of my code for reference.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin
SESSION_ID, INSTANCE =SalesforceLogin(username=SFDC_USER_NAME,password=SFDC_PSTRING)
SF=Salesforce(instance=INSTANCE,session_id=SESSION_ID)
SOQL = "SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE {} >= {} and {} < {}".format(','.join(SOURCE_FIELD_NAMES_FINAL),SOURCE_TABLE,LAST_PARAM_FILTER_FIELD,PRM_START_DATETIME_SFDC,LAST_PARAM_FILTER_FIELD,PRM_END_DATETIME_SFDC)
SOQL_BULK = SOQL + "|" + str(SFDC_TIME_OUT_LIMIT)
SFDC_BULK_API_CALL = "QUERY_RESULT = SF.bulk.{}.query(SOQL_BULK)".format(SOURCE_TABLE)
exec(SFDC_BULK_API_CALL)
```

**Note: I can only access the Salesforce account via code and don't have UI privileges.**

Comment: Strikes me you need to check whether the timeout is due to the specific table, or some related table, due to pre-query processing. Use the query plan tool. If it is the query, you need to consider applying a specific `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and your own "pagination" that repeats the queries with appropriate constraints.